# Unity Editor Script: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<internal>'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a tower defense game. In the first version, I was using a simple text format for levels. It was very basic and the parsed had to be maintained each time I add a new level property. I have discovered serialization and written load and save from/to binary files. For that I have a serializable class that looks like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class LevelData {
public string filename;
public List<List<Tile>> grid;
public List<Vector2> waypoints;
public int width;
public int length;

public Vector2 startPos;
public Vector2 finishPos;

public List<TowerInfo> towers;
public List<WaveData> waveChain;
}
```

Now I would like to add an Editor script to my LevelManager that parses the old text file format and turns them into binary format. This is my editor script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(LevelManager))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class LevelManagerEditor : Editor {
public string levelFilename;

public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
    DrawDefaultInspector();
    if(GUILayout.Button("Load level " + levelFilename + " and serialize")) {
​        LevelData levelData;
        ParseFromFile(out levelData);
        Debug.Log("Parsing " + levelFilename + " successful!");
        SaveLevel(levelData);
        Debug.Log("Saved serialized level");
    }
}
private void ParseFromFile(out LevelData levelData) {
    levelData = new LevelData();
    levelData.filename = levelFilename;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(levelFilename + ".txt");

    string line;
    int y = 0;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        if (line[0] == '#') break;
        List<Tile> row = new List<Tile>();
        for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++) {
            switch(line[x]) {
                case '.':
                    row.Add(Tile.NORMAL_BRICK);
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    row.Add(Tile.PATH_BRICK);
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    row.Add(Tile.START_BLOCK);
                    levelData.startPos = new Vector2(x, y);
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    row.Add(Tile.FINISH_BLOCK);
                    levelData.finishPos = new Vector2(x, y);
                    break;
                default:break;
            }
        }
        levelData.grid.Add(row);
        levelData.width = row.Count;
        y++;
    }
    levelData.length = y;
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        levelData.waypoints.Add(ParseWaypoints(line));
    }
    file.Close();
}
private Vector2 ParseWaypoints(string line) {
    string[] tokens = line.Split(' ');
    return new Vector2(int.Parse(tokens[0]), int.Parse(tokens[1]));
}
private void SaveLevel(LevelData levelData) {
    string pathToLevel = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + levelData.filename + ".dat";
    FileStream file = File.Create(pathToLevel);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(file, levelData);
}
}
```

This is the compiler error:
Assets/Tower Defense Assets/Scripts/Utilities/LevelManagerEditor.cs(17,5): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<internal>'

when I double click on it it points me to the `LevelData levelData;` declaration inside OnInspectorGUI()

I dont understand the error. Please help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I figurer it out.. I had an unprintable char on that line. I had to delete that line and rewrite it.

Comment: Absolutely! It appears to be a single occurrence of [U+200B, 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), before all the usual spaces on that line. I do not know how you happened to introduce that. What editor or development environment (Visual Studio?) are you using. Maybe some obscure key combination (that you accidentally used) will produce this character? Or maybe you copied some code from a "rich" text file, like a word processing document or a web page?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015. No I havent copy pasted a code snippet, though I may have Alt+numpad something without noticing, weird lol!

the first time, I had the levelData set as a member variable of my editor class. when I compiled it gave me the same error but on that line. I then thought that maybe somehow I was not allowed to use a user defined class as a member variable on an editor script so I moved the line by Alt+DownArrow. It told me the same error at the new location so I thought it had something to do with my LevelData class. Really confused me